# Can't understand what 2 symbols are on a nautical chart on the northern cost of Alaska

Tags: maps

I need to figure out two symbols that appear multiple times along the coast and rivers of Alaska

[image].

The symbols can't be buoys, seabeds, Archipelagicsealanes, etc. i believe squares with a dot inside indicate submerged rocks, sandbanks, or any other obstruction in the water that can be a danger to navigation. Then the circles with brown interiors and gray borders may represent muddy or sandy bottom areas since they continue far into the rivers.

Here's the code used for filtering the unwanted elements of the nautical chart:

```
setAllIsolatedDangers(false);
setArchipelagicSeaLanes(false);
setBoundariesAndLimits(false);
setBuoysBeaconsAidsToNavigation(false);
setBuoysBeaconsStructures(false);
setChartScaleBoundaries(false);
setDepthContours(false);
setDryingLine(false);
setLights(false);
setMagneticVariation(false);
setOtherMiscellaneous(false);
setProhibitedAndRestrictedAreas(false);
setSeabed(false);
setShipsRoutingSystemsAndFerryRoutes(false);
setSpotSoundings(false);
setStandardMiscellaneous(false);
setSubmarineCablesAndPipelines(false);
setTidal(false);
```

I've looked up the symbols on the official USA navigation charts but no symbol is as the ones i have. Still, some present resemblance to buoys and Silos symbols.